# How to redirect Homepage.aspx to an MVC default route?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

We're developing a new system to replace an existing system.

The new system is ASP.NET MVC so we're defining routes to our controllers and actions as normal.

The old system as traditional ASP.NET so the URLs consist of lots of .aspx pages.

We want to set up redirects so that when a user tries to access `/Homepage.aspx` (lots of users would have that bookmarked), they'll get redirected to the new system's default route, which is just `/`

What is the best way for me to do this?

**edit:** @Chance suggested below that I specify the route:

`routes.MapRoute("Homepage", "Homepage.aspx", new { controller = "controller", action = "homepage" });`

This works, but I'd like to do a redirect because I don't want `Homepage.aspx` in the address bar. Is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may take a look at the [following blog post](http://www.eworldui.net/blog/post/2008/04/ASPNET-MVC---Legacy-Url-Routing.aspx) which illustrates how you could implement a legacy route handler which will perform 301 permanent redirects.

Comment: this did the trick, though it should be noted that the code in the blog post itself doesn't work. However, the code in the sample project he's linked to does: http://www.eworldui.net/files/MvcDemos/LegacyRouting.zip

Comment: I tried using this sample but I don't see 301 in fiddler and the old url is still in the browser. Internally it redirects to the view I want, how do I show the new url in the browser?

Comment: link given, does not open.

Answer (score 4):

Put this code in your global.asax file:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    if (Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().Contains("homepage.aspx"))
    {            
        // use RedirectPermanent for 301, or Redirect for 302
        Context.Response.RedirectPermanent("/");
    }
}
```

You could modify this code to apply to other old ".aspx" pages as well.

Answer (score 1):

you can just give your default controller/action an additional route that is hardcoded. Ie

`routes.MapRoute("Homepage", "Homepage.aspx", new { controller = "controller", action = "homepage" });`

Comment: This works, but I'd like to do a redirect because I don't want `Homepage.aspx` in the address bar.

Comment: This did not work for me, anything I would be missing other than the above code? I am using MVC3.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to simply create a static page to replace HomePage.aspx with a meta redirect.  This would allow you to present the user with a message informing them that the site has changed, and urge them to update their bookmarks.

You can extend this to the entire site by creating a custom error handler for 404 that points to either a static page, or a specific URL.