# Converting web forms site to MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, redirect

This seems like a common question, but I cannot find an answer anywhere.

First some background. I have an ASP.NET website with ASPX web forms. When a browser requests **http://www.mysite.com/somefolder/** then IIS serves the contents of **/somefolder/default.aspx**. Requests for **http://www.mysite.com/somefolder/default.aspx** also receive **/somefolder/default.aspx**.

Now for the question. I want to gradually convert the site to MVC and Razor. What needs to be done so that requests for **http://www.mysite.com/somefolder/** are handled by MVC and requests for **http://www.mysite.com/somefolder/default.aspx** get a 301 redirect to **http://www.mysite.com/somefolder/**?

**EDIT**

Here's some additional information that may clarify my question above.

In the past, whenever I "retired" an ASPX page I would place a `Response.RedirectPermanent` in its code-behind to redirect to the replacement page. Should that practice be continued in this scenario when **default.aspx** is replaced by MVC/Razor or should something different occur (such as deleting **default.aspx** and using routing to handle requests for **http://www.mysite.com/somefolder/default.aspx**)?

Comment: Here's something that might be what you're looking to do: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntegratingASPNETMVC3IntoExistingUpgradedASPNET4WebFormsApplications.aspx

Comment: That's a good article @CAbbott, but I didn't see where it addressed my question.

Comment: You may look at this post: [How to redirect Homepage.aspx to an MVC default route?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4626166/690329) and it's accepted answer.

Comment: @afzalulh: I'm new to MVC and its routing mechanism, so it take will me some time to try what you mentioned. (It looks promising though!)

Comment: implement base routeconfig and then add filters to your project .. this would be more concise solution...

Comment: @vishal sharma: I am inexperienced with routing and filters. Can you provide details?

Comment: @afzalulh - The post and its accepted answer don't address my question.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT :**  There's an easy solution for this. In the Route.Config, add `routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.aspx/{*pathInfo}");` :

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.aspx/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

And in the Global.asax.cs add this:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var requestUrl = Request.Url.ToString().ToLower();

    //Default.aspx is converted to "Home/Index"
    if (requestUrl.Contains("/default.aspx"))
    {
        Context.Response.StatusCode = 301;
        Context.Response.Redirect("/Home/Index");
    }
}
```

You may need to parse `requestUrl` in case parameters are passed to the page.

I would suggest to read this: [ASP.NET MVC - Legacy Url Routing](http://www.eworldui.net/blog/post/2008/04/ASPNET-MVC---Legacy-Url-Routing.aspx) which would help to build a better solution.

Comment: Please pardon my ignorance, but what happens, using this solution, if http://www.mysite.com/somefolder/default.aspx is requested and /somefolder/default.aspx has not been converted to MVC? Won't IIS and the client get into an infinite loop with the browser requesting /somefolder/default.aspx, IIS saying to redirect to /somefolder/default.aspx, the browser requesting /somefolder/default.aspx again, IIS redirecting again, etc.?

Comment: @Theophilus - No, if the page exists, it will pass (note `"{id}.aspx",`). One issue I did not notice, if the file doesnot exist, it will go to infinite loop. I have edited my answer.

Comment: After a very long delay I am able resume this issue. I made the changes you suggested except in Global.asax.cs the contents of the requestUrl.Contains method was changed to `"/somefolder/"` since I am concerned about redirection at the subfolder level instead of the root. When I attempt to browser to /somefolder/, Firefox reports "The page isn't redirecting properly".