# Routing an ASP page to a Action in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am recreating a site from VB .NET to MVC 4 ASP.NET. In the old project there is a system that sends an email to a user and within that email there is a hyperlink that can direct the user to view the specific task. I want to make all of the old emails work with the new recreated site. Here is an example of the hyperlink in the old system:

```
http://pppweb/accounting/ap/default.asp?etaskid=32698
```

And here is an example of what a hyperlink looks on the new system.

```
http://pppweb/accounting/ap/ApIssues/Task/32698
```

So I was thinking i could create a default.asp page in my MVC project and try and have it parse the taskID out. I am not exactly sure the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to redirect Homepage.aspx to an MVC default route?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626166/how-to-redirect-homepage-aspx-to-an-mvc-default-route)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise against adding a classic `.asp` (not `.aspx`?) page in your project, since I'm not even sure there is a way to do that. You can, assuming you are running IIS7, map the url:

```
http://pppweb/accounting/ap/default.asp
```

to be handled by MVC by adding the following line to your `web.config` file:

```
<configuration>
...
   <system.webServer>
...
      <handlers>
...
         <add name="aspnet htm" path="account/api/default.asp" verb="*" type="System.Web.Mvc.MvcHttpHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" />
```

Then, add a route for that url and requests should resolve to the normal route parameters you specify. From that point, you should be able to access `etaskid` from the query string easily enough.

Edit:

Alternatively, if the url matters a lot to you, you can specify a redirect rule from the old format url to the new one by using UrlRewrite module (also an IIS 7 feature). You can read about it here: http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite